# Link a sign in to another site without giving out password

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

Is there a way that I can have a button in my website's portal that logs people in to another website without revealing to them the credentials?

Comment: Say I have an admin portal on my website, and I want anyone with access to be able to login to Twitter with the click of a button, wihtout them having to enter the username or password.

Comment: I bet you are looking for this... https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

Comment: That was just an example, I have several websites I wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) or alternatives